# node.js walk a directory alphabetically recursive

Tags: javascript, file, node.js, unix, alphabetical

Is there any way to walk a directory alphabetically but recursive?

I've been using: https://github.com/substack/node-findit to walk but it's not alphabetical.

It works based on readdir while I need something similar to php's scandir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort the results from readdir. You can patch node-findit and use it.